# jQuery UI datepicker options as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a number of inputs on a page function as JQ UI datepicker. Each needs to have different settings. I want to minimize the JS so I save the settings as an attribute in each individual .

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" size="20" value="" options="{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeYear: true,yearRange: '1920:2010'}" />

<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="expdate" id="expdate" size="20" value="" options="{ yearRange: '2011:2020'}" />
```

I use js to load the options dynamically as the settings.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".datepicker").each(function(index){
  $(this).datepicker("option" , $(this).attr('options'));
 });
});
```

datepicker is not functioning. If I empty the parentheses after $this.datepicker it works fine.

I have also tried another way to assign settings. ("option",...) no dice.

Comment: In fact, the specification w3c attribute options do not exist, you tried to substitute other attributes, such as @ title or @ alt, which unfortunately is also not used in the tags input?

Comment: man.. if it does not exist that doesnt mean you cant add it. adding the attr is perfectly fine there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).datepicker(eval('(' + $(this).attr('options') + ')'));
```

Or use a json parser http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 2):

essentially your are doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").each(function(index){
        $(this).datepicker("option" , "{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeYear: true,yearRange: '1920:2010'}" );
    });
});
```

when you need to be doing either

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeYear: true,yearRange: '1920:2010'});
});
```

or this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker("option" , "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd');
    $(".datepicker").datepicker("option" , "changeYear", true);
    $(".datepicker").datepicker("option" , "yearRange", '1920:2010');
});
```

The first solution initiates the datepicker with a set of options, while the second solution initiates a datepicker, and then sets individual options. Your version was trying to be some hybrid of the two, and tried to use a string instead of an object literal encased in curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `eval` ([which is evil](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#evil), btw) you can use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) like this:

```
$(this).datepicker( "option" , $.parseJSON( $(this).attr('options')) );
```

However, you should be careful to have valid JSON string.